# Forms django -> is_valid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am currently developping an application on django and when i send a post request from a form, is_valid method return false, but form.is_bound return True.

my form.error ->

mail

This field is required.

prenom

This field is required.

nom

This field is required.

my forms.py

```
from django import forms

class formadduser(forms.Form):
    mail = forms.CharField(label='Mail', max_length=40)
    # imput_username = forms.CharField(input='input_username', max_length=100)
    prenom = forms.CharField(label='Prénom', max_length=25)
    # input_password = forms.CharField(input='input_pathword', max_length=100)
    nom = forms.CharField(label = 'Nom', max_length=25)
```

views.py where i'm trying to get the form inputs:

```
from re import S
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, QueryDict
from .forms import formadduser

import pickle
import os
from .fonctions import tri
from .models import Users
# Create your views here.
def administrator(request) :
    # test = request.POST[username]
    # print(test)
    # request.form['username'] je crois que c'est du flask 
    return render(request, 'admin.html')
    
    

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
      var = request.POST["username"]
      print(var)
    text = """<h1>{{var}}</h1>
            <p>les crepes nananinanana</p>"""
    return HttpResponse(text)
    
def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = formadduser(request.POST)
        print(form)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            print("debug")
            print(form.cleaned_data["mail"])
            var = Users(mail = form.cleaned_data["Mail"], prenom = form.cleaned_data["Prenom"], nom = form.cleaned_data["Nom"])
            var.save()
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # print(NameForm.username)
            # redirect to a new URL:
            # return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
            # Username = form.cleaned_data
            # text = """<h1>{{form.cleaned_data["username"]}}</h1>
            # <p>les crepes nananinanana</p>"""
            # return HttpResponse(text)
            # print(form.cleaned_data["username"])
            # u = USERS(Username = form.cleaned_data["username"], droits = form.cleaned_data["droits"])
            # u.save()
            # query = pickle.loads("zeubi")
            # test = list(USERS.objects.values("Username"))
            # test = USERS.objects.values("Username") 
            
            # test = USERS.objects.all()
            
            # test = str(USERS.objects.values("droits"))
            # res = tri(test)
            # user_qs = USERS.objects.all()
            # for user in user_qs:
            #     print(user['Username'])
            # testv = QueryDict
            # test.query = query       
            return render(request, 'admin.html')
            # return render(request, 'admin.html', {'test' : test})
            # return(locals())
            # USERS.Username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            # return form.cleaned_data
        else:
            print("invalid form")
            print(form.is_bound)
            # print(form.errors)
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        print("error")
        form = formadduser()
    return render(request, 'admin.html', {'form': form})
```

templates.py with 4 forms but my test is on formadduser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ADMIN</title>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'global/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'administrator/admin.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'administrator/admin.css' %}"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'global/StyleGlobal.css' %}">
</head>

<body id="idbody" onclick="fout();foutform()">
    <div class="bande">
            <div onclick="testhb()" id="hb">
                <div class="barre"></div>
                <div class="barre"></div>
                <div class="barre"></div>
                <ul id="ulmenu">
                    <li class="menu"><a class="textdeco" href="http://10.75.101.201/Front/mat/mat.html">Materiel</a></li>
                    <li class="menu"><a class="textdeco" href="http://10.75.101.201/Front/offrecgr/offrecgr.html">Offres/CGR</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <!-- </div>  -->
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="{% static 'global/GHD.png' %}" alt="Logo">
            <!-- <a href="adv.html" class = "ghdsharepoint"></a> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="titre">
        <h1 class="accueiltxt">ADMIN</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="gigacontainer" id="gigacontainer">
        <div class="containerbutton">
            <div class="button" id="buttonsuppuser" onclick = "buttonsuppuser()">
                <p class="trashcan"></p></div>
            <div class="button" id="buttonadduser" onclick="buttonadduser()">+</div>
            <div class="txtbutton">Users</div>
            <div class="button" id="buttonsuppapp" onclick = "buttonsuppapp()"></div>
            <div class="button" id="buttonaddapp" onclick = "buttonaddapp()">+ </div>
            <div class="txtbutton">Apps</div>
        </div>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form" id="formsuppuser">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="suppuser">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="suppuser" id="suppuser">
            <button>Supprimer</button>
        </form>

        <form name="formadduser" action="" method="post" class="form" id="formadduser">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="addusermail">Mail</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="addusermail" id="addusermail">
            <label for="adduserprenom">Prénom</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="adduserprenom" id="adduserprenom">
            <label for="addusernom">Nom</label>
            <input required="required" type="text" name="addusernom" id="addusernom">
            <button type="submit">Ajouter</button>
        </form>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form" id="formsuppapp">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="suppapp">Application</label>
            <input type="text" name="suppapp" id="suppapp">
            <button>Supprimer</button>
        </form>

        <form action="" method="post" class="form" id="formaddapp">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="addapp">Application</label>
            <input type="text" name="addapp" id="addapp">
            <button>Ajouter</button>
        </form>
    </div>


        
        
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have the errors in `form.errors`, without them, we cannot tell you anything.

It may also be that your form is not bound (request data have not be sent to the form). You can check this with `form.is_bound`.
If this return false, you did not send your data into your form:

```py
form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
```

You can see how `is_valid` works in the [django source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0dd29209091280ccf34e07c9468746c396b7778e/django/forms/forms.py#L203).
As you can see, you can know whats wrong juste by checking `form.is_bound` or `form.errors`.

Comment: print(form.errors) -> output : <ul class="errorlist"><li>mail<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>prenom<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>nom<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>

Comment: and print(form.is_bound) -> output : True

Comment: Well, here is your response: `mail`, `prenom` and `nom` are empty. Either your POST request does not have this fields (or they are empty), or you are not sending them correctly in the form. You haven't provided any information that could help us check this (View or template).

Comment: tanks you for your awnser, i edited the topic with views and templates.

Comment: Your django  form expects 3 fields: *mail*, *nom* and *prenom*. Your HTM form defines 3 fields *addusermail*, *addusernom* and *adduserprenom*... This will not work, you need to name them  the same way as your Django form. You shoud use `{{ form.as_p }}` to see how your HTML form is generated by django.